# Unable to execute commands against an offline database when I am trying to connect Oracle offline

Tags: mysql, oracle, offline, liquibase

I am using the below code:

```
private static String file="create-table.yml";
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Database database =createOfflineDatabase("offline:oracle");
    Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(file, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
    liquibase.update("test");
    liquibase.dropAll();
}

private static Database createOfflineDatabase(String url) throws Exception {
    DatabaseConnection databaseConnection = new OfflineConnection(url, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor());
    return DatabaseFactory.getInstance().openDatabase(url, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Getting this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set create-table.yml::create-table.yml::vishwakarma:
 Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Cannot execute commands against an offline database
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:619)
at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:188)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:181)
at com.test.liquibase.LiquibaseTest.main(LiquibaseTest.java:27)
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing something? Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Excuse me, but - what is an "offline" Oracle database? I know that *datafiles* can be put offline and - as such - can't be accessed until they are put back online. Or, is it a database that is shut down? It is not accessible either. So, as far as I understand the question, you should stop trying to do what you are doing as it just won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The Liquibase class you are using and that is in most example code doesn't seem to have an "updateSQL". You can programmatically invoke the main method passing in the necessary `--url` parameters to get it to do the work. for example:

```java
        liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(new String[]{"--changeLogFile=src/test/resources/db.changelog.xml"
                ,"--outputFile=target/updateSql.txt"
                ,"--url=offline:unknown?outputLiquibaseSql=true"
                , "updateSQL"});
```

Will generate:

```sql
-- *********************************************************************
-- Update Database Script
-- *********************************************************************
-- Change Log: src/test/resources/db.changelog.xml
-- Ran at: 12/04/20 11:51
-- Against: null@offline:unknown?outputLiquibaseSql=true
-- Liquibase version: 3.8.9
-- *********************************************************************

CREATE TABLE DATABASECHANGELOG (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED datetime NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED INT NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), COMMENTS VARCHAR(255), TAG VARCHAR(255), LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20), CONTEXTS VARCHAR(255), LABELS VARCHAR(255), DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR(10));

-- Changeset src/test/resources/db.changelog.xml::createTable-example::liquibase-docs
CREATE TABLE public.person (address VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES ('createTable-example', 'liquibase-docs', 'src/test/resources/db.changelog.xml', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1, '8:49e8eb557129b33d282c4ad2fdc5d4d9', 'createTable tableName=person', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '3.8.9', '6688703163');
```

And also outputs a `databasechangelog.csv` that tracks what should be the state of the DATABASECHANGELOG  for subsequent runs.

If you edit the code to load "db.changelog2.xml" with something new in it with a different ID and tell it to write out the sql to a new file that will only have the second change set in it. This is because the `databasechangelog.csv` will be used to know what was previously run. The CSV will then be updated for the next time:

```
"ID","AUTHOR","FILENAME","DATEEXECUTED","ORDEREXECUTED","EXECTYPE","MD5SUM","DESCRIPTION","COMMENTS","TAG","LIQUIBASE","CONTEXTS","LABELS","DEPLOYMENT_ID"
"createTable-example","liquibase-docs","src/test/resources/db.changelog.xml","2020-04-12T12:10:16.989","2","EXECUTED","8:49e8eb557129b33d282c4ad2fdc5d4d9","createTable tableName=person","","","3.8.9","()","","6689816939"
"createTable-example2","liquibase-docs","src/test/resources/db.changelog2.xml","2020-04-12T12:26:56.664","4","EXECUTED","8:3740614394b969eeb1edcc9fd0187bdb","createTable tableName=person2",,"","3.8.9","()","","6690816645"
```

**Warning:** It seems that if you call the main method directly it will internally call `System.exit()` so if you really wanted to run `updateSQL` inside a tool you will need to look at the code inside that main class to figure out how to do it without the JVM being terminated by `System.exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Offline databases are something that Liquibase came up with to allow you to generate SQL for updating a database that the liquibase user is not able to update directly - they are not able to be updated. See [this documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/offline.html) for more details about offline databases.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question of how you use it. also the documentation doesn't say how to use it and clicking on the links at that link isn't helpful.